# Генератор Java классов из базы данных Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Есть веб-сервис на Java. Есть БД Oracle.
Как написать код, который может просканировать базу и создать готовые Java объекты (классы), так, чтобы когда вносишь изменения в БД (удаление, добавление, переименование полей), чтобы автоматически генерировались новые классы?
Подскажите в каком направлении гуглить или может есть готовые фреймворки?

Comment: Вам нужна ORM. Почитайте про Hibernate